# Get Record Id on checkbox click salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have below code where i am displaying all the accounts with checkbox. I want when i check one checkbox i should get that record Id in console. Is i am doing in correct way.

Below is the code -

```
<aura:component controller="SimpleAccountController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
<aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
 <aura:attribute name="accountRows" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedCount" type="integer" default="0"  access="GLOBAL"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cssStyle" type="String" />
  <!--  <style>{!v.cssStyle}</style>  --> 

    <style>
  .forceStyle .viewport .oneHeader.slds-global-header_container {
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
    </style>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getAllAccounts}" />

  <div class="slds-m-around--xx-large">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.openModel}">Open Modal</button>    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">

      <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header99" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open " aura:id="Modalbox">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
          <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick="{!c.closeModel}">
            X
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h2 id="header99" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Modal</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
            <p><b>Modal is Open
              </b>

                <div class="container">
                    <p>
                        <b> List of Accounts </b>
                    </p>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Action</th>
                                <th><strong> Id </strong></th>
                                <th> <strong>  Name </strong> </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <aura:iteration var="cell" items="{!v.accountRows}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" label="Select?" change="{!c.onCheck}" text="{!cell.Id}"/></td>

                                    <td> <a href="{! '/'+cell.Id}" data-recId="{!cell.Id}"> {!cell.Id} </a> </td>
                                    <td> {!cell.Name}  </td>
                                </tr>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-modal__footer">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.closeModel}" >Cancel</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.likenClose}">Like and Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open" aura:id="MB-Back"></div>

 </aura:if>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller -

```
 onCheck: function(component, event, helper) {
        var checkCmp = component.find("checkbox");
        var label = component.get("v.text");
       console.log(label);
        //console.log("value : " + checkCmp.get("v.text"));
   },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the checkboxes are inside the iteration, you will need to iterate over the checkbox rendered in DOM. sample code here to fetch text of checkbox of all the selected ones

```
var getAllCheckboxes = component.find("checkbox");
for (var i = 0; i < getAllCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    if (getAllCheckboxes[i].get("v.value") == true) {

        console.log(getAllCheckboxes[i].get("v.text"));
    }
}
```

For each/specific checkbox, you should be able fetch using (replace 'value' with attribute to be fetched)

`event.currentTarget.value` OR `event.target.value`

Note: You can fetch the value and text using below code for lightning component version < 40.0

```
console.log(event.getSource().get("v.value"));
console.log(event.getSource().get("v.text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it works like that, but did you try `checkCmp.component.get("v.text");`

In general try to output your `checkCmp` and see what kind of methods and attributes it has: `console.log(checkCmp);`

Answer (score 0):

You can get this from event instance which returns which element got clicked

```
onCheck: function(component, event, helper) {
        var selectedCheckbox = event.target.text;
   },
```